# How to play widevine drm content in android webview

Tags: android, video, webview, drm, widevine

I want to play `widevine drm` content in `webview` android using `html5` code.
I tried a lot not succeeded, does `widevine` not supported in `webview`?
please give a way to play `widevine` in `webview` android and let me know if `widevine` does not support in `widevine` and why?

Any help and suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: See also https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=526058

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the webview shipped with Android devices differs between devices and between Android versions.

There is an excellent overview here:

- http://slides.com/html5test/the-android-browser#/42

You can test whether your device supports it by using an open source HTML5 player like Shaka in your webview and trying some of their demo content.

Shakaplayer includes a basic tutorial showing how to include the player in a webpage:

- https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/tutorial-basic-usage.html

You can also use a test app like the HTML5test Webview app - checking the streaming section to make sure MSE and DRM are both ticked:

- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.html5test.webview&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Widevine is supported on Android WebView. The following [test page](https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/support.html), can be loaded on the `WebView` to confirm that.

There is a `drm` key in the response:

```
  "drm": {
    "com.widevine.alpha": {
      "persistentState": false
    }
  }
```

However, to ensure that Widevine is properly activated you need to make sure that you are loading the content within a secure context. You can read about secure contexts [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts). Quoting:

> A secure context is a Window or Worker for which certain minimum standards of authentication and confidentiality are met. Many Web APIs and features are accessible only in a secure context. The primary goal of secure contexts is to prevent MITM attackers from accessing powerful APIs that could further compromise the victim of an attack.

In particular, don't use the [loadData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#loadData(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method as that wouldn't give you a secure context. Quoting the relevant part of the documentation:

> Content loaded using this method will have a window.origin value of "null". This must not be considered to be a trusted origin by the application or by any JavaScript code running inside the WebView (for example, event sources in DOM event handlers or web messages), because malicious content can also create frames with a null origin. If you need to identify the main frame's origin in a trustworthy way, you should use loadDataWithBaseURL() with a valid HTTP or HTTPS base URL to set the origin.

Instead it is recommended to use [loadDataWithBaseURL()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Finally, note that Widevine comes with 3 different levels of certification (L1, L2 and L3). L1 being the highest, using the Trusted Execution Environment. AFAIK, L1 may still not be supported yet
on WebViews as shown by this [code review comment](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/517704/6/android_webview/browser/aw_content_browser_client.cc#225):

> Unless there's some other hidden magic, I believe so. We'll enable L1 on WebView when AndroidOverlay is supported on WebView.

Note that this comment dates from 2017, so not sure whether it is still relevant. The point is that another reason why this wouldn't work is if decrypting the code requires L1 level and either your device or the WebView don't support it.

Hope that helps.