# Is there any way we can play YouTube video on AR Core augmented image in Android?

Tags: arcore, youtubeplayer

I have a requirement of playing a YouTube video on augmented image. I'm trying to play a YouTube video on a augmented image using YouTube player API. But, the issue is video is not showing only audio is playing. Can anyone help me achieve my requirement?

Here is my xml file which I'm using for YouTube player view. I have used 3rd party library to load YouTube video.

```
<com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/youTubePlayer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:showYouTubeButton="false"
app:videoId="pIAQV0u72iI"
app:showFullScreenButton="false" />
```

Here is me sceneform class for YouTube which i'm adding for YouTube videos.

```
class SwarmSceneYouTube(val image: AugmentedImage?, val arItemData: ArListData?) :
AugmentedImageNodeGroup() {
    override fun onInit() {
        YouTubeVideoNode().init(anchorNode, this, image, arItemData)
    }
}

class YouTubeVideoNode : AugmentedImageNode(ArResources.youTubeRenderable) {
    override fun initLayout() {
    super.initLayout()
        val youTubePlayer = ArResources.youTubeRenderable.get().view.youTubePlayer
    }
    override fun modifyLayout() {
        super.modifyLayout()
        localRotation = ArResources.youTubeRenderableRotation
    }
}
```

Comment: That sounds like it may be a DRM issue - how are you embedding the video, can you share some code?

Comment: I have edited my question. this is what i'm doing to load a youtube video @Mick

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using a specific library to embed the video.

This repository does not appear to have had any updates in the last last 17 months, but you will see there are some issues listed similar to your one:

- https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player/issues/651
- https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player/issues/646

It would be good to add you example to those discussions.

Although it is not marked as closed the most promising fix is likely this note:

> Sir I debug this issue it rises when Android System WebView disabled and google chrome working is default web interface. once
> Android System WebView enabled its gone automatically

Android WebView functionality can differ between devices so there can be issues with support for some features. This has been know to affect DRM in particular which in turn will often show the symptoms you are seeing of audio but no video playback. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47688092/334402

Given the lack of recent activity it would probably be good to check the official YouTube API also.